# Overriding silent mode with Expo AV

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-av

Has anyone managed to override the silent mode switch to autoplay sounds using Expo AV? I'm looking to do so for a timer feature that I have in my app so I wouldn't be able to rely on user interaction to play the sound.

I have tried playsInSilentModeIOS: true, with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

In your `App.tsx/App.js`, above function declaration, write this

```js
if (Platform.OS === "ios")
  Audio.setAudioModeAsync({ playsInSilentModeIOS: true });
```

Comment: I already had this (kinda) in my configureaudio, wouldn't the below be the same?
async function configureAudio() {
    try {
        const audioSettings = {
            shouldDuckAndroid: true,
            interruptionModeAndroid: Audio.INTERRUPTION_MODE_ANDROID_DO_NOT_MIX,
        };
        if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
            audioSettings.interruptionModeIOS = Audio.INTERRUPTION_MODE_IOS_DO_NOT_MIX;
            audioSettings.playsInSilentModeIOS = true;
        }
        await Audio.setAudioModeAsync(audioSettings);
    } 
}